# Why cant i load this sprite?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

i load a sprite sheet to cache :

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"candys%i.plist",stage]];
```

than, trying to use it with sprite :

```
 fruit1 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"candy%i_1.png",stage]];
```

and it says it doesnt find the file `candy1_1` , when the file is actually there, and i have even remove and add it again .

There is a sprite sheet called `candys1.png` ,and in it there are `candy1_1.png`,`candy1_2.png` ..
of course the `.plist` is there also .
Whats the problem here ??

Comment: could you post a slice of your .plist file?

Comment: @sergio how can i do that ? (i must say, after creating it, i have changed the names in the plist ,only the file names ,but did it OUTSIDE xcode, and than drag it in.. is it a problem ? i had to change than and could not create them all again .

Comment: if your havenabled retina, the files (plist and .png) should have the -hd.plist and -hd.png suffixes, BUT not the frame names.

Comment: from what i know ,till now, all my apps that made only for retina, did not used the -hd , so , hows that ?

Comment: YvesLeBorg- you solve my problem - i took out the suffix ! but this is because i have never use it till now, because its not a 3g compatible and only retina anyway, so why now ?

Comment: not sure how you setup your project, dont know which version of cocos2d. But typically, cocos2d will search an 'extended' file with the extension appropriate for the running environment (-hd, -ipadhd, ... etc). In your code, dont specify the "device extension" in file names, BUT include files with the appropriate device extension. Also, in plists, dont put a device extension on frame names. This way, your code remains constant for all devices, you dont need to 'if this or that use this or that' file or frame.